# Getting WhatsApp to work for both networks on a dual-SIM phone

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, dual-sim

I have been using WhatsApp for a very long time in a dual mobile HTC Desire U under a specific network. Now, I would like to use WhatsApp for the other network too.

Is it possible to use watsapp for both networks under a single roof? I have tried suggestions many other sources, but I did not find any solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can install one app per phone So you cannot use it for more than 1 network in the same phone(dual sim phone)

From [Whatsapp FAQ](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/general/21009863)

> Your WhatsApp account can only be verified with one number, on one
>   device. If you have a dual SIM phone, please note that you still must
>   choose one number to verify with WhatsApp. There is no option to have
>   a WhatsApp account with two phone numbers. If you attempt to
>   frequently switch your WhatsApp account between different devices, at
>   a certain point, you may be blocked from re-verifying your account. So
>   please do not repeatedly switch between different devices.

Answer (score 0):

You are saying that you want to use whatsapp for another phone number of yours???
It is possible to create one whatsapp account for a single number. You cant combine two whatsapp accounts into one.
If you want to create independent accounts for both your phone numbers and use whatsapp for them from your only phone then it is hell of a difficult thing.
you have to logout every single time to get into the another account of yours. Otherwise you should have two whatsapp apps in your phone that is impossible.